# Google Play Console Not Working for Designed Famililies

Tags: android, google-play-console

I submitted a app to play store but it was rejected because it does not comply with the Designed for Families program requirements. i received a mail from google play support saying-

**Next Steps:**

1. Make the necessary changes to your app.
2. Submit your app for another review.

**Or, if you’d like to exclude your app from Designed for Families:**

1. Remove Designed for Families from your app’s Pricing & Distribution settings.
2. Click Submit update.

I decided to select the second option that means i wanted to opt out from that program that google mentioned.Then i sign-in my play console account and in price and distribution section i unchecked the *Designed for Families* and resubmit the app but suddenly its showing an error that i attached below.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSgFu.png)

If anyone faced this problem before please help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app developed for families or children.If so make sure you comply with the rules and regulations for family apps.Remove all ad pop-ups and put in a user-friendly interface. If your app is not designed for children then uncheck the box with 'primarily child-directed'.

Comment: when i unchecked the box its showing an error, actually its not working

Comment: when unchecking its saying that "You are required to opt in to the Designed for Families program because you indicated that your app is primarily directed towards children." . what can i do now??

Comment: There is a checkbox saying primarily directed for children .uncheck it.

Comment: If you feel this answer is helpful, please tick the green check.

Comment: i tired this but did not helped me.

Comment: Reset everything and try again from the first.This may be due to updation issues